# How to store the auto increment value into a php variable?

Tags: php, sql, auto-increment

I have written my sql below and it works. As I've set my particulars_id to autoincrement, i have to use Last_Insert_ID() in order for the database to use the next id using auto increment. However, i would like to store that value into a php variable. Is that possible?

```
 $addquery = "INSERT INTO Particulars (Particulars_ID, Name, Identification_Number, Number, Nationality, Status, Remarks)
                    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$_POST[newname]', '$_POST[newic]','$_POST[newnumber]','$_POST[newnationality]','$_POST[newstatus]','$_POST[newremarks]')";
```

Comment: What mysql lib do you use?

Comment: Be carefull using the $_POST variables in the query directly. This makes your website vulnerable to an SQL injection.

Comment: first of all db itself take care about auto-incremented column also `$last_id = ladt_insert_id();` you can do like this but it will only available till the program execution. So what you exactly mean `store the auto increment value into a php variable?`

Comment: @Anant yes like what your codes suggest, i want to set the id into the a variable. The reason why i want to set into a variable is because i have another form where the user will have to insert their expertise and i have created a database table particulars_expertise where it stores the particulars_id and expertise as the primary key (composite keys). So if i can store the particulars_id, i can then use the id to set them in the composite for the next form.

Comment: @u_mulder hmm im not sure what you do you mean by mysql lib. sorry newbie here haha but im using mysqli

Comment: so go for it and send it to other form

Comment: @Dragony ohh then what do you suggest so that i dont have to use $_post in my sql statement? thanks a load!:)

Comment: @Anant So do you suggest i store it in a session? so i can just use that variable in another form? and also for your code $last_id = last_insert_id() where do i put it? because i'm not sure if the ide know what table i am referring to..

Comment: 1. you can save it in session or directly send it to another form through get method (appending the data into the url). 2. you can use that code just after executing a query.

Comment: @Samuel Check the answer from dimlucas

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a row into a table that has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field that field will be incremented automatically as the name implies. You don't need to tell MySQL to increment it, you don't have to provide a value for the auto-increment field **at all**.

So to begin with, remove the call to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from your query:

```
$addquery = "INSERT INTO Particulars (Name, Identification_Number, Number, Nationality, Status, Remarks)
                '$_POST[newname]', '$_POST[newic]','$_POST[newnumber]','$_POST[newnationality]','$_POST[newstatus]','$_POST[newremarks]')";
```

Notice how I completely removed the `Particulars_ID` from the query.

Second, this is not directly related to your question but your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection. When accepting user input you should avoid concatenating it to your query, instead use Prepared Statements and modify your query like this:

```
$addquery = "INSERT INTO Particulars (Name, Identification_Number, Number, Nationality, Status, Remarks)
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

You can then prepare a statement and bind the values from `$_POST`. This essentially sanitizes user input. Read more about prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

**START OF EDIT**

An example of binding the real values to the `?` placeholders using `PDO`:

```
//First prepare the statemt
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO Particulars (Name, Identification_Number, Number,Nationality, Status, Remarks)
              VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
//Start binding values to placeholders
$db->bindValue(1, $_POST['name']);
$db->bindValue(2, $_POST['Identification_Number'];
$db->bindValue(3, $_POST['Number'];
//Bind the rest of the values in the same way
```

**END OF EDIT**

About the id of the last inserted row you will need to run a separate query to get it. So after you run the above query and if insertion is successful you can 
run a query like this:

`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id FROM Pariculars`

Comment: ohhh hi im quite new to this. Just to confirm, is sql injection something like if a person type into the textbox 1=1, it will still allow the user to get in? and also if i change it to values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"; then where do i set my $_POST as those values? thanks a load!:)

Comment: @Samuel Yes that's kind of what SQL Injection is. You bind the real values to placeholders using a binding method after preparing the statement. There various ways to do that. I edited my answer to include an example but that's not the only way to do it. Check `mysqli` prepared statements and `PDO` prepared statements to find what suits you best